# Select tag option border blue and on hover blue background in Chrome [Duplicate but did not find solution anywhere]

Tags: angularjs, html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I am trying to remove **blue border** from select tag option and blue background on hover. I searched and saw many solution here but none of them helped. Few codes, helped in changing background but did not get what I want to achieve. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[Sample Code Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkj1ptza/7/)

```
CSS:
.form-control:disabled, .form-control[readonly]

{

    background-color: #ffffff !important;

}

select:required:invalid 

{

  color: #999999;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

}

option[value=""][disabled]

{

  display: none;

}

option 

{

  color: #404041;

}

select{

   -webkit-appearance: none;

}

.form-control:focus 

{

    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-color: #979797 !important;

}

select:focus,button:focus 

{

    outline: none !important;

}
```

Comment: Make a custom select if you want to customize how it looks.

Comment: to my knowledge it is impossible to change the hover color as this is the default color rendered by the browser

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunetely it's impossible unless you build without using `<select>` yourself.

**Read this:**
[How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option